Which property contains SYSTEM PRIVATE include directories?
CMake target_include_directories documentation says that when using SYSTEM argument with PUBLIC or INTERFACE it populates INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES, however it completely ignores scenario when the command specifies SYSTEM PRIVATE combination:
target_include_directories(targ SYSTEM PRIVATE ...)

This command, however, works as expected and applies -isystem compilation flags (when using gcc), but it remains unclear if there is a CMake property which stores these directories and if no, is there a way to read them afterwards?
